# Css 100% height: footer scrolling in to content when re-sizing page

Tags: css

I been following a tutorial for making my webpage css 100% height from this [SITE](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html). I been able to achieve what i want but now I am having an issue with my footer. Every time I resize the page smaller the footer will slightly scroll upwards into the content. Is there a way i can stop that? Here is my [Live EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test/)

Thank you

**css**

```
<style>
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%; /* needed for container min-height */
    background:#333333;
    font-family: trebuchet, 'trebuchet ms', 'tahoma', sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    color:#5e5e5e;
    line-height: 130%;
}


/****** COLORBLOCK: this is the orangey-yellow bar behind the wrapper in the background. ******/

#colorblock {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #c69a55;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/**************************************************/



div#container {
    position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
    margin:0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */
    width:925px;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/
    min-height:100%; /* real browsers */
    border-right: 15px solid #000000;
    border-left: 15px solid #000000;

}

div#contentArea {
    padding:1em 1em 5em; /* bottom padding for footer */

}
    div#contentArea p {
        text-align:justify;
        padding:0 1em;
    }

#content {
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    background: #ebebeb;
    padding: 5px;
    width:635px;
    height: 400px;

}

/****** TOP BANNER: This is the banner with Greg's List logo and main navigation. Also includes the styles for the main navigation links. ******/
div#header {
    /*padding:1em;*/
    height: 175px;
    border-top:15px solid #000000;

}
    div#header p {
        margin:0;
    }



/****** LEFT COLUMN: This is the left gray column next to the content. Features the styling for the log-in form and the location links. ******/

#left2 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background: #dddddd;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 400px;
}


/****** FOOTER: This is the junk at the bottom of the page. Do NOT remove the clear div; it's what makes it stick to the bottom. ******/


div#footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0; /* stick to bottom */
    background:#7A7A7A;
    border-bottom:15px solid #000000;
}
    div#footer p {
        padding:1em;
        margin:0;
    }

a.footer {
    color: #c7c7c7;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}   


p { 
    margin:0 0 1em;
}   

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-bottom:60px;` to the `#content` css definition.

Full block:

```
#content {
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    background: #ebebeb;
    padding: 5px;
    width:635px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an explicit height set on your content div, you could do:

`padding-bottom:36px;` on your div#container line 32

But if your content div changes in height, it may not account for that padding anymore.